# Python xlwt module, hide grid

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm trying to hide grid on successfully generated .xls with 2 sheets included. I read the xlwt doc and among other properties that can be set on xlwt-related objects, there is show_grid function included. I was trying following, but it doesn't change anything:

```
with open(os.path.join('sheet1_test.csv'), 'rb') as cf:
    reader = csv.reader(cf)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                sheet1.write(c, r, col, easyxf(
                'font: name Arial;',
                'show_grid: off'
                ))
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Tweaking the first example [here](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2011/04/examples-generating-excel-documents-using-pythons-xlwt/):

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'ascii')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('My Worksheet')
worksheet.show_grid = False # "show_grid" is a property of the worksheet!
worksheet.write(0, 0, label = 'Row 0, Column 0 Value')
workbook.save('Excel_Workbook.xls')
```

You can see that `show_grid` is a property of the worksheet, not a cell option for `easyxf`.
(`show_grid` turns off the grid in the worksheet)

Comment: It makes sense, thanks for your answer, I'll take a look, even though the problem had been already solved